# Getting PayPal Balance (GetBalance API)

Tags: java, paypal

I've been searching through the PayPal documentation for two hours and cannot find the answer to this, even searched Google.

Checked here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#api-operations

I've added PayPal's SDK in Maven (REST API), and now I am unsure what to do.

I want to get the balance of an account using the PayPal API (all currencies).

Comment: I would recommend using this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) instead.  It uses the Classic API, but it has samples/templates that are fully functional and ready to go.  GetBalance is the easiest call, of course, and the sample itself would work for you out of the box.  [Click here for a look at the GetBalance sample](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/GetBalance.php).

Comment: Ah, shoot.  Nevermind, I just saw that you're using Java.

Comment: I'll have a look, since I'm a PHP developer anyway. :)

Answer (score 6):

GetBalance is from the Classic APIs and is not yet included in the REST APIs at this time, but you may directly implement the NVP call with HTTPRequest as this,

API Endpoint:

```
https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
```

POST request payload:

```
USER=seller_api1.paypal.com
&PWD=56A9R4JPVFPMER2X
&SIGNATURE=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AociN2kspFBnMbzOGg6NdiC7ZXtg
&VERSION=109.0
&METHOD=GetBalance
&RETURNALLCURRENCIES=1
```

Response:

```
L_AMT0=265.17
L_CURRENCYCODE0=USD
TIMESTAMP=2015-08-09T14:21:25Z
CORRELATIONID=802b0b6666022
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=000000
```

As well you may obtain the [Classic API SDKs](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/) with your prefered programming language, and select "Merchant" SDK this time.

My sample PHP code to help you understand the flow,

```php
<?php
$version = "124";
$user = "API UserName";
$pwd = "API Password";
$signature = "API Signature";
$API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";

$resArray = CallGetBalance ( $API_Endpoint, $version, $user, $pwd, $signature );
$ack = strtoupper ( $resArray ["ACK"] );
if ($ack == "SUCCESS") {
    $balance = urldecode ( $resArray ["L_AMT0"] );
    $currency = urldecode ( $resArray ["L_CURRENCYCODE0"] );
    echo "Account Balance: " . $balance . " " . $currency;
}


function CallGetBalance($API_Endpoint, $version, $user, $pwd, $signature) {
    // setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    
    // NVPRequest for submitting to server
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=GetBalance" . "&RETURNALLCURRENCIES=1" . "&VERSION=" . $version . "&PWD=" . $pwd . "&USER=" . $user . "&SIGNATURE=" . $signature;
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq );
    $response = curl_exec ( $ch );
    
    $nvpResArray = deformatNVP ( $response );
    
    curl_close ( $ch );
    
    return $nvpResArray;
}

/*
 * This function will take NVPString and convert it to an Associative Array and it will decode the response. It is usefull to search for a particular key and displaying arrays. @nvpstr is NVPString. @nvpArray is Associative Array.
 */
function deformatNVP($nvpstr) {
    $intial = 0;
    $nvpArray = array ();
    
    while ( strlen ( $nvpstr ) ) {
        // postion of Key
        $keypos = strpos ( $nvpstr, '=' );
        // position of value
        $valuepos = strpos ( $nvpstr, '&' ) ? strpos ( $nvpstr, '&' ) : strlen ( $nvpstr );
        
        /* getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array */
        $keyval = substr ( $nvpstr, $intial, $keypos );
        $valval = substr ( $nvpstr, $keypos + 1, $valuepos - $keypos - 1 );
        // decoding the respose
        $nvpArray [urldecode ( $keyval )] = urldecode ( $valval );
        $nvpstr = substr ( $nvpstr, $valuepos + 1, strlen ( $nvpstr ) );
    }
    return $nvpArray;
}

?>
```

Comment: Is the SIGNATURE their API key thing from the website?

Comment: Exactly, login to the PayPal account, and find "API access" under the "profile" tab

Comment: The PHP example doesn't really help people who need help with this in Java, could you post some resources for Java people to use?

Comment: You may get the SDK with your preferred programming language here: http://paypal.github.io/sdk/   Select "Merchant" SDK for your requirement

Comment: Good enough, but I'd have expected some Java stuff, since the question was for Java.

Answer (score 5):

So for anybody else struggling with this question there is an API endpoint under "Transaction Search" part of the documentation which makes no sense at all.

```
GET /v1/reporting/balances
```

You will get a list of balances one for each currency you maintain on your account.

See the documentation here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/

Comment: This is only available to those who are in the PayPal partner network. 

"Use the Transaction Search API to get the history of transactions for a PayPal account. To use the API on behalf of third parties, you must be part of the PayPal partner network. Reach out to your partner manager for the next steps. To enroll in the partner program, see Partner with PayPal. For more information about the API, see the Transaction Search API Integration Guide." - [Transaction API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those who are looking for REST API for node js or without any SDK.

GetBalance (To get balance for a particular account)

Doc Link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/limited-release/balance-accounts/v2/api/

REST API [GET]: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/wallet/balance-accounts

REQ:

```bash
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/wallet/balance-accounts \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

RES:

```
{
  "total_available": {
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "value": "2800"
  },
  "total_reserved": {
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "value": "1920"
  },
  "balance_accounts": [
    {
      "available": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "1000.00"
      },
      "reserved": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "00.00"
      },
      "links": []
    },
    {
      "available": {
        "currency_code": "AUD",
        "value": "1000"
      },
      "reserved": {
        "currency_code": "AUD",
        "value": "00.00"
      }
    },
    {
      "available": {
        "currency_code": "CAD",
        "value": "1000"
      },
      "reserved": {
        "currency_code": "CAD",
        "value": "100"
      },
      "links": []
    },
    {
      "available": {
        "currency_code": "GBP",
        "value": "1000"
      },
      "reserved": {
        "currency_code": "GBP",
        "value": "1000"
      },
      "links": []
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/wallets/balance-accounts"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It says permission denied and I couldn't find any option while creating the app which may provide balance query permissions.

Comment: same I also couldn't find @VikasSinghal , did you found anything now?

Comment: This API is only for PayPal Partners, such as, Banks. That is why we have `permission denied` error